# Tomcat 6 thread safe email queue (javax.mail.*)

Tags: queue, tomcat6, jakarta-mail

Hi I have design/architecture question.  I would like to send emails from one of my jsp pages.  I have one particular issue that has been a little bit of a problem.  there is an instance where one of the pages will need to send around 50 emails at near the same time.  I would like the messages sent to a queue where a background thread will actually do the email sending.  What is the appropriate way to solve this problem?  If you know of a tutorial, example code or tomcat configuration is needed please let me know.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is rather sound: append the messages to a internal queue and then let some background task handle them.

Here are a few pointers that may be useful:

- Unless you want to go distributed (in which case you should look at JMS), use a [`BlockingQueue`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) implementation for your queue. In your background thread, just do an infinite loop while `take()`-ing messages from the queue. Those classes take care of potential concurrency issues for you.
- Use a [`ServletContextListener`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) to set up your background thread when your Web application starts and when it is stopped.

One possible problem with using a raw `BlockingQueue` is that when your Web application is stopped, all the messages in the queue are lost. If that's a serious problem, then it would probably be easiest just to use a database for the queue and to use `notify()` to wake up your background thread, which then processes all requests from the database.

Comment: One more question how do you access the thread that the contextListener has started?

Comment: Keep the reference to either the queue or the thread (preferrably the thread) in a static variable or in a property of the `ServletContext`. Or, preferrably, if you use some IoC container like Spring to build your application, let it take care of the injection for you.